# Cloudformation + OpsWorks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I would like to use Cloud formation to create a OpsWorks stack.

Using Cloudformation, it is possible to create an EC2 instance using: `AWS::EC2::Instance`. To add an instance to a OpsWorks stack I use `AWS::OpsWorks::Instance`.

Is it possible to reference an `AWS::EC2::Instance` inside `AWS::OpsWorks::Instance`?

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to register outside resources to OpsWorks with CloudFormation (e.g. pre-existing EC2 instances, RDS clusters, ECS clusters).

To do so you either talk directly to the OpsWorks api via an aws-sdk or the aws-cli.

If you have no specific reason to do otherwise, I'd say creating instances directly with AWS::OpsWorks::Instance is the best way to go.

Alternatively, if you need to do specific things to the instance you cannot from OpsWorks (like using a specific Elastic IP), then you can use cloud-init to have the instance use aws-cli to register *itself* to an pre-existing OpsWorks stack and layer. This article explains some commands you can execute to automate registering an instance to an existing stack: http://lrascao.github.io/opsworks-provisioned-auto-scaling-groups/

In short, try directly creating instances within OpsWorks, if it works for you, you're done.